# Как удалить связку ключей в xubuntu?

Tags: linux, xubuntu

Была установлена **связка ключей** для приложения `remmina`. Спустя некоторое время пароль был забыт. Как мне удалить эту **связку ключей** или сбросить пароль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы удалить связку ключей от `remmina` выполняем команды:

```
cd ~
cd .local/share/
sudo rm -R keyrings
sudo rm -R remmina
```

Ответ на данный [вопрос](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113740/how-to-remove-a-keychain-in-xubuntu/1113750#1113750).

Перезапускаем `remina`.